# How to debug GKE load balancer or ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the following problem:

In around 50 percent of the requests, the request hits the right ingress (I can confirm on the logs), and the other percent goes to another ingress that has an invalid certificate.

I tried to list all ingresses

```
kubectl get ingress -A | grep domain
```

But only me returns the valid ingress (which one that receive the HTTP)

Is there some way to debug Google load balancer on the main ingress in order to see the "routes"?

I want to confirm if is there some "dangling" ingress that still receiving requests

EDIT:

I can confirm that the requests are going limbo following the logs.

The question is: Who is handling these requests?

```
kubectl logs -f -n namespace ingress
```

Comment: Can you provide the ingress config yaml file which can help in further resolving the issue?

Comment: We'd definitely need to see your Ingress resource definition as mentioned in the comment above.  Also, how are you differentiating requests?  Are you just making requests with different paths?

Comment: Can you provide more details on  **other 50 percent of the traffic not hitting the right ingress.**